# How many datanodes used to do mapper for multi small files in one hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have one NameNode(Hadoop-Master) and three DataNodes(Hadoop-Master,Hadoop-Slave1,Hadoop-Slave2). Hadoop-Master is used for both NameNode and a DataNode. The OS is Ubuntu 16.04. The version of Hadoop is 2.7.6. The block size is 128MB. HDFS is configured with two replication. 
I have ten files in HDFS (/file1,/file2,.../file10) , each is 127MB, so each file only in one block. Those files are distributed in three datanodes. **But I don't know why all files have a replication in Hadoop-Master (as DataNode)**. The other two DataNodes (Hadoop-Slave1 and Hadoop-Slave2) have different files' replication.
 I write a Java MapReduce program to process all ten files. Using following codes to add all files for the Job:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath( job , new Path("/file1"));
FileInputFormat.addInputPath( job , new Path("/file2"));
... ...
FileInputFormat.addInputPath( job , new Path("/file10"));
```

After the Job is done, I read the console log. It seems only Hadoop-Master do all the mapper and reducer work. The other two datanodes do not appear in the console log.
I actually want all DataNode process these files parallelly. For example, Hadoop-Master process file1~file4, Hadoop-Slave1 process file5~file7, and Hadoop-Slave2 process file8~file10.
What should I do to make all DataNode process the Job.

Comment: You should put all related files in a single folder and give that folder as the input path rather than list out one-by-one every file

Comment: thank you cricket_007. What should I do , if I only want to process some of files under a single folder?

Comment: Then they shouldn't be in that folder :) By the way, In my four years of using Hadoop, I have seen no company actually writing plain mapreduce code. That being said, in Spark at least, you would be able to filter out filenames. I'm sure there is a way to do it from MapReduce, somehow